# How do you put a select query into a dynamic parameter

Tags: dynamic, parameters, crystal-reports

I am wondering if there is a way to place a select statement or filter into a Dynamic Parameter.

For example, lets says I have a table called Customers.  Within the table there is a field called Last Name.

I want a parameter list box that lists all of the customers so I create a dynamic parameter and uses Table Customer.LastName.

Now, I want to filter the Customers that are available in the list box to only show customers whose last name starts with an A or B.

So when a user runs the report, they only can choose from Customers whose name starts with A or B and all other customers are not listed.

Is there a way to accomplish this in Crystal XI?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a command , set a where clause to show just names starting with A and B and set the dynamic parameter to use this command. If you would like to make this command dependent by another parameter , for example in parameter 1 to insert the letter D and in parameter 2 to see just names starting with letter D then you can add parameter 1 to the command and still use it to get parameter 2 values. The report will behave a little weird because it will first ask you for a letter and then will show a second dialog to ask for name , but will work